# What is something that the same to @@error in DB2?

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, db2

I want to handle exception in DB2. The exception can be anything that we don't know in advance (lost connection or anything).

In SQL Server, I can do that, something like:

```
DECLARE @i_Error INTEGER
DECLARE @i_Row  INTEGER

UPDATE Table_Name
SET Column_Name1 = 'Value1'
WHERE Column_Name2 = 'Value2'

SELECT  @i_Error = @@ERROR,
        @i_Row = @@ROWCOUNT

IF @i_Error <> 0
    GOTO ExitRoutine


ExitRoutine:
    -- Something to exit here
```

`@@ERROR` exists in SQL Server, but DB2 does not, so how can I do the same thing in DB2?

Comment: What Db2 version and platform? Are you looking into SQL functions and procedures or SQL in general?

Comment: Hi data_henrik. I am using IBM Data Studi version 4.1.3
It should be in SP, script. I need to handle that to avoid any accident while queries/Statements executed. Thank you!

Comment: Data Studio is a tool which works with several database system. I asked about the Db2 server you are working with. Db2 has exception handling in SQL procedures

Comment: Thanks data_henrik, I am researching exception handling in SQL procedures.

Answer (score 3):

Db2 on  most platforms offers [ANSI SQL PL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0020290.html) , which you can use inside either named blocks (routines(functions, stored procedures), and in triggers ) and also in anonymous blocks.

With ANSI SQL PL, your code can use structured exception handling to catch and respond to errors. If you have not previous worked with structured exception handlers then there is a learning curve.

Blocks of SQL PL code can use continue-handlers or exit-handlers or undo-handlers to catch errors and react to errors. Such exception handlers can expose the [SQLCODE and SQLSTATE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0009028.html) values that the execution of some SQL statements can set.  Blocks can be nested, and each block can have its own exception handlers. Also available are related statements [SIGNAL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004232.html) and [RESIGNAL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005654.html) for throwing exceptions and [GET DIAGNOSTICS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005647.html) statement to access return status, row_count, and error details.  Some of these are version dependent and there can be platform specific variations.

Exception-handlers can be [declared](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html) for specific conditions or for general cases. You can have multiple handlers, each for different kinds of condition and different kind of response (continue, exit, undo).

You need to be aware of **default** exit handlers  in stored procedures, that may immediately exit on any negative SQLCODE.

Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows also offers an emulation of Oracle PL/SQL when specifically configured, and in this case Oracle style syntax is available for handling errors.

When programming with embedded-SQL in a 3GL (like C or C++ or COBOL etc) then different concepts apply and the SQLCODE and SQLSTATE are exposed with another technique.

Comment: It's informative. Thanks for your answer.